# TypeORM for Cassandra

Tags: node.js, typescript, cassandra

Can I use TypeORM for cassandra db? Or is there any similar typescript library for cassandra? I have found some modules like cassandra-driver but it doesn't have feature like TypeORM @entities. Can I use both of these modules together?

Comment: nodejs driver from datastax has some support for Typescript: https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/09/typescript-support-datastax-nodejs-drivers, and also has an object mapper

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately No, that  Cassandra section has not been completed yet.

but you can use: https://github.com/ifaim/nestjs-express-cassandra

for more learning about Cassandra in Nestjs: https://express-cassandra.readthedocs.io/en/stable/datatypes/

I use this repo for our enterprise project.